# How to use remote debugging on RaspPi using PyCharm with X11 forwarding

Tags: python, ssh, remote

I am trying to make a small app using Python, OpenCV on my RasPi. For this I've selected using PyCharm on my Windows machine and use its remote deployment and debugging feature.

This is also all good. The only problem is when I try to debug my Python code I get a display error because the Python console does not have an Xserver as I understand it.

Is there anyone to fix this ? If not, remote development through PyCharm is kind of pointless.

Comment: Have you tried running a X Server for Windows in parallel ? XMing perhaps ?

Comment: i can use mobaterm which have a build in xserver. can i redirect the output to this? .. I also have a monitor connected to the Raspi where when i run raspivid through ssh redirects its own output. just not sure how to achive this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working by using MobaXterm with its Xserver.

Start mobaXterm.

find what display its running on mine was :0.0

set DISPLAY=:0.0 in pycharm for the console and it worked.